# grep XML value and export it if it contains number

Tags: regex, xml, terminal, grep

I have an XML file which contains links to products, and category, each category ends with word and slash like https://url.com/category/subcatgory and they are bounded inside `<loc> </loc>`

However each product has link which end on 6 digit number, for example https://url.com/category/subcategory/product-name-of-something-154555

I am trying to grep this while i get the file with wget, so I am experimenting only on the grep part now, I know how to get the file, and open it.

This is the code I have been running but is exporting all links even the categories.

`grep -Po "(?<=<loc>)(.*)[0-9]{6}/(?=</loc>)" nameofmyfile.xml`

But I succeed to grep each 6 digit code with this code:

`grep -oP "(?<=<loc>)*[0-9]{6}/(?=</loc>)" nameofmyfile.xml`

but then again I need the part in front of that link cause I only get: 666444/ when running this.

The file structure is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <url>
        <loc>https://somelink.com/category/building-materials/concrete/hand-tools/</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-09-11T02:10:42+02:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://somelink.com/category/building-materials/concrete/hand-tools/screws/screws-145890/</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-09-11T02:11:06+02:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
        <url>
        <loc>https://somelink.com/category/building-materials/concrete/hand-tools/screws/screws-145489/</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-09-11T02:11:14+02:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://somelink.com/category/building-materials/concrete/hand-tools/hammer/hammer-145488/</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-09-11T02:10:42+02:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://somelink.com/category/inside/heating/floor-heating/pert-222-010274/</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-09-11T02:11:06+02:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
        <url>
        <loc>https://somelink.com/category/building-materials/paint/</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-09-11T02:11:14+02:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://somelink.com/category/building-materials/screws-and-nails/</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-09-11T02:10:42+02:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://somelink.com/category/building-materials/concrete/power-toools/</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-09-11T02:11:06+02:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
        <url>
        <loc>https://somelink.com/category/inside/heating/floor-heating/pert-182-010272/</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-09-11T02:11:14+02:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://somelink.com/category/inside/heating/floor-heating/pert-202-010273/</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-09-11T02:10:42+02:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
    <url>
        <loc>https://somelink.com/category/inside/bathroom/</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-09-11T02:11:06+02:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
        <url>
        <loc>https://somelink.com/category/inside/pipes/draining-pipes-168544/</loc>
        <lastmod>2022-09-11T02:11:14+02:00</lastmod>
        <changefreq>weekly</changefreq>
        <priority>0.8</priority>
    </url>
</xml>
```

How can I extract all links which ends on -XXXXXX/ and skip the other? and they are inside the `<loc> </loc>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use grep to get the numbers only:

```
<loc>[^>]*\K\d{6}(?=/</loc>)
```

**Explanation**

- `<loc>` Match literally
- `[^>]*` Optionally match any char except `>`
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `[0-9]{6}` Match 6 digits
- `(?=/</loc>)` Positive lookahead, assert `/</loc>` to the right

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/h3L0BC/1).

Example

```
grep -Po "<loc>[^>]*\K\d{6}(?=/</loc>)" nameofmyfile.xml
```

Output

```
145890
145489
145488
010274
010272
010273
168544
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

@The fourth bird

Have you grep with regex solution that will contain the complete URL inside the `<loc> </loc>` that has the 6 digit numbers?

I need to match and export the complete URL for example

`https://somelink.com/category/inside/heating/floor-heating/pert-182-010272/
Not only the numbers.`

Comment: @user3453440 Then you can move the `\K` to right after the closing bracket `<loc>\K[^>]*\d{6}(?=/</loc>)` See https://regex101.com/r/xGCy9a/1

Answer (score 1):

`xmllint`can be used after `wget`to get the links ending in `-<6 numbers>`.
The trick is to substitute numbers with underscores and then detecting that

```
cat tmp.xml | xmllint  --xpath '//*[local-name()="loc" and contains(translate(.,"0123456789","__________"), "-______")]/text()' tmp.xml -
```

result

```
https://somelink.com/category/building-materials/concrete/hand-tools/screws/screws-145890/
https://somelink.com/category/building-materials/concrete/hand-tools/screws/screws-145489/
https://somelink.com/category/building-materials/concrete/hand-tools/hammer/hammer-145488/
https://somelink.com/category/inside/heating/floor-heating/pert-222-010274/
https://somelink.com/category/inside/heating/floor-heating/pert-182-010272/
https://somelink.com/category/inside/heating/floor-heating/pert-202-010273/
https://somelink.com/category/inside/pipes/draining-pipes-168544/
```

or saving wget ouput to a tmp file

```
(echo "setrootns"; echo 'cat //defaultns:loc[contains(translate(.,"0123456789","__________"), "-______")]/text()') | xmllint  --shell tmp.xml | grep -v ' ----'
```

result

```
/ > setrootns
/ > cat //defaultns:loc[contains(translate(.,"0123456789","__________"), "-______")]/text()
https://somelink.com/category/building-materials/concrete/hand-tools/screws/screws-145890/
https://somelink.com/category/building-materials/concrete/hand-tools/screws/screws-145489/
https://somelink.com/category/building-materials/concrete/hand-tools/hammer/hammer-145488/
https://somelink.com/category/inside/heating/floor-heating/pert-222-010274/
https://somelink.com/category/inside/heating/floor-heating/pert-182-010272/
https://somelink.com/category/inside/heating/floor-heating/pert-202-010273/
https://somelink.com/category/inside/pipes/draining-pipes-168544/
/ >
```

Comment: Hello LMC

Thank you for your support and help, I can see with your command I can get the links like I wanted them.

So I would love to import the results into a TXT file, which is updated with this command with a Cronjob.

Can you show me an example of a code which include the wget + extract + saving to a file.

`wget -qO- "https://somelink.com/nameofmyfile.xml" | (echo "setrootns"; echo 'cat //defaultns:loc[contains(translate(.,"0123456789","__________"), "-______")]/text()' | xmllint  --shell tmp.xml | grep -v ' ----' 
setrootns
warning: failed to load external entity "tmp.xml`

Comment: `wget -q ... -O tmp.xml; (echo ...)`

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`. Simple explanation would be, setting `RS`(record separator) as regex `(^|\n[[:space:]]+)<loc>[^<]*<\\/loc>\n` and then in main program checking condition and removing unnecessary parts from its value. Then checking if `<loc>.....</loc>` part is having 6 digits after `-`(last slash of that line before `</loc>`) if yes then printing it as per requirement.

```
awk -v RS='(^|\n[[:space:]]+)<loc>[^<]*<\\/loc>\n' '
RT{
  num=split(RT,arr,"[-/]")
  if(arr[num-2]~/^[0-9]{6}$/){
     print arr[num-2]
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Here is the [Online demo](https://regex101.com/r/FlUarJ/1) for used regex.

***NOTE:*** In regex demo site, capturing group is changed to non-capturing group AND double escape is NOT used for `/` to make it clear as per regex site but one should use regex used in above code only in GNU `awk`.